# What happens if employment cannot be verified because the company went out of business?

Tags: interviewing

What happens if employment cannot be verified because the company went out of business?

Comment: Welcome to workplace.se.. you will need to write this up into a bit more detail if you want to avoid it being closed. (There may be a duplicate or similar question on here already) e.g.. Is this for a background check? What industry, type of company? (e.g. working for government, a private company, listed company?) How long ago was the "non verified job" and is it your most recent job? Is there anyone from that company who could verify the employment even though they presumably don't work there any more?

Comment: Please add your country tag. In my country I'd say: not a problem, your written certificate letter is still perfectly intact and you can show it. Other countries might prefer other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

For most employers, **this won't be an issue or seen as a negative in reviewing your resume/application.** There are a variety of ways that background-checking agencies can verify that you were employed even if the business is no longer operating.

If you're concerned that you won't be able to provide a reference, you should **consider asking a previous manager to act a reference, even if they are no longer employed at the same firm.** You might be able to reach previous managers on LinkedIn if you don't have recent contact info.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you cannot prove your employment at a company.  You should be able to show your old pay stubs, as well as state and federal tax records that prove your previous employment.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a verification letter from your previous manager and colleagues , with a proof of pay.